# Django で表示は問題ないが、不可解な事が起きており困っております。

Tags: python, django

下記のコードを実行したターミナルの結果です。このようなエラーが起きます。
しかし、テンプレートには問題なくcontextが渡されていて表示の問題ないです。
これはdjangoのバグでしょうか？このエラーは消えないのでしょうか？

**ターミナルの出力:**

```
kyoto
['kyoto city', 'Fushimi', 'Maizuru', 'Fukuchiyama']
[06/Dec/2023 10:14:27] "GET /kyoto/ HTTP/1.1" 200 0
 
  File "shops\views.py", line 24, in get_context_data
    print(sub_area[region])
         ~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^
```

ちなみにですが、以下のようにregionに値を直接入れるとエラーは消えます。

一部を書き換えた例:

```
class ToppageView(TemplateView):
        template_name = 'shop/index.html'
    
        def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
            region = self.kwargs.get('region')

    　　　　region = "kyoto" #←追加

            print(region)
            print(sub_area[region])
            
            context['region'] = region
            context['sub_area'] = sub_area[region]
            return context
```

##### 現状のコード

views.py

```
sub_area = {
    'kyoto':['kyoto city', 'Fushimi', 'Maizuru', 'Fukuchiyama'],
}

class ToppageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'shop/index.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        region = self.kwargs.get('region')

        print(region)
        print(sub_area[region])

    　　context['region'] = region
        context['sub_area'] = sub_area[region]
        return context
```

Comment: 書かれている部分にエラーだという記述が見当たりませんが、エラーはこれで全部ですか？

Comment: すみません。エラーではないのかもしれませんが、これで全部になります。
あまり気にしなくてもいいのでしょうか？
 File "shops\views.py", line 24, in get_context_data
    print(sub_area[region])
~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^

Comment: sub_area[region]の下に~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^が書かれているので、この部分でエラーが起きているのかと思っておりました

Comment: そうですね、`^^^` などは何らかのエラーか警告の位置を示している筈です。
通常はその内容が説明されるはずですが、それが無いのは確かに不可解ですね。
何らかのリンター系のツールの表示が混じっているのでしょうか。
例えば、`region` が `None` になる可能性を警告しているかも知れません。
`region = self.kwargs.get('region', 'kyoto')` などとしてデフォルト値を指定するとどうなりますか？

Comment: region = self.kwargs.get('region', 'kyoto') これで試してみましたが,何も変わらないですね。region = 'kyoto'これを追加すると消えるのですが、ほんと不思議です。

Comment: すみません、関係ないと思い一行省いていたコードがありましたので修正しました。context['region'] = regionこの行ですが、実際はregionもcontextに渡しております。　path('<str:region>/', ToppageView.as_view(), name='shop_top'), こちらがpathになります。テンプレート内ではこのregionを{% url 'shop_top' region=region %}このようにパラメーターに使用しております。urlのパラメータで渡されたregionをさらにテンプレート内でパラメータとして使用していることによってregion が None になる可能性を警告しているのでしょうか？

Comment: context['sub_area'] = sub_area[region]　この行を消しても警告は消えます。context['region'] = regionこの部分に警告が入る事はないです。

Comment: あとは、`sub_area[region]` が `KeyError` になる可能性ですとか、すごくリンター系のツールに指摘されそうな箇所ではあります。
しかし、何の説明も無く場所だけ示されるというのは何かおかしいと思います。
下記手順を試して、ターミナルの表示を全て貼り付けてみて下さい。何かヒントが得られるかも知れません。
〔1. 新規に起動したターミナルで作業を開始して、他のツールが動いていないことを確実にする。〕
〔2. `python --version`〕
〔3. `python manage.py --version`〕
〔4. `python manage.py runserver`〕
〔5. `/kyoto/` にアクセスし、問題のメッセージを出させる〕
〔6. `/foobar/` にアクセスし、通常のエラー表示を出させる〕
〔7. `Ctrl-C` で終了させて、次のプロンプトが出るまで待つ〕

Answer (score 1):

Faviconの設定をしたら表示が出なくなりました。お手数をおかけしました。親切に対応して頂きありがとうございました。